# WinSCP .NET Assembly FTP server does not release session when connection is closed

Tags: c#, session, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to do a simple download of some files from an FTP server. I am using the .NET Assembly that WinSCP provides. The source FTP server has a setting that does not allow more than 3 sessions, so I need to disconnect once the files are downloaded. I am able to connect to the server, because every time I try to run the program 4 times, it disallows the session.open saying that the max sessions allowed is 3. Then I have to reboot the machine to end the sessions.

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_close

Am I doing something incorrectly? At this point I'm just trying to get the Connect and the Disconnect portion to work. I'm kinda new to this and would appreciate your help.

```
using System;
using WinSCP;

class FTPDownload2
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Setup session options
        SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
        {
            Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
            HostName = "name",
            UserName = "uname",
            Password = "pwd!"
        };

        using (Session session = new Session())
        {
            // Connect
            session.Open(sessionOptions);
            session.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nimesh! neither Close(), Abort(), or Disconnect would work but the session.ExecuteCommand("quit") worked like a charm. Thanks again!

Comment: It's a bug in the server if it does not release resources for the session when the connection is closed without `QUIT` command. The [RFC 959](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) says in section 4.1.1.  Access Control Commands:  *"An unexpected close on the control connection will cause the server to **take the effective action of** an abort (`ABOR`) and **a logout (`QUIT`).**"* Most FTP clients do not send the `QUIT` command.

Comment: I think you are correct this is an application server that supports FTP backup. It must either be a bug or a security setting to not allow more than three sessions in a given time frame. If I walk away and come back for 30 minutes, the sessions seem to be released.